# Twig compilation anomaly on different os

Tags: php, twig

[Twig 2.0, php 7.0.17] Can someone explain what happend in my twig file after compilation?

On mac everything works fine but on debian server somethigs gone wrong but i dont understand what. Thats my twig file

```
{% if object.something is defined %}
    <span>Huray</span>
{% endif %}
```

Output on mac (render):

```
<span>Huray</span>
```

Output on debian:

```
<span>Huray</span> { {
```

I try add some extra text after span for example "test".

```
{% if object.something is defined %}
    <span>Huray</span>test
{% endif %}
```

Output on debian was.

```
<span>Huray</span> {est {
```

I use Twig to render part of site which is included into the normal php template. After compiling it looks like replacement doesnt match twig tags.

Can someone explain what happend? I think its something in Twig Compiler but i dont know what is it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so problem was in different php extesnion settings. **MBSTRING** on server had different setup for **mbstring.func_overload**. It was old settings created mainly for php 4.x. After changing this option value to **zero** everything works fine.